# Where LLVM interpreter is looking for external functions (libraries?)

Tags: assembly, llvm, system-calls, llvm-ir

I am playing with LLVM IR a little and I cannot resolve (with help of google and doc) where LLVM interpreter `lli` is looking for external (not explicidly defined functions. I mean basic system functions). For example if I want to write simple program with no dependencies, on linux which will write something on screen I can do something like that:

```
@message = private constant [12 x i8] c"hello world\0A"
define i32 @puts(i8* %s) {
    call i32 asm sideeffect "movl $$0x2, %edi\0Amovl $$0xC, %edx\0Amovl$$1, %eax\0Asyscall\0A", "=A,{si}"(i8* %s) #1
    ret i32 %1
}
define void @exit(i32 %c) {
    call i32 asm sideeffect "movl $$60, %eax\0Asyscall\0A", "=A,{di}"(i32 %c) #1
    ret void
}
define void @main() {
    getelementptr [12 x i8], [12 x i8]* @message, i64 0, i64 0
    call i32 @puts(i8* %1)
    call void @exit(i32 0)
    ret void
}
define void @_start() {
    call void @main()
    ret void
}
```

`main` and `_start` are for cross compatibility with `ld` and `lli`. So above code works same in both. I can `lli` this, and code will start from `main`, or `llc` then `ld` it and it also will work, thus code will start from `_start` as expected. Now if I write code:

```
@formatString = private constant [4 x i8] c"%d\0A\00" 
declare i32 @printf(i8*, ...)
define i32 @main() {
    %d = shl i32 2, 3
    %s = getelementptr [4 x i8], [4 x i8]* @formatString, i64 0, i64 0
    %call = call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* %s, i32 %d)
    ret i32 0
}
```

It also works in `lli` but I cannot `ld` it because `ld` do not know reference to `printf` which is also expected. I can include prepare `ld` parameters to make that code work also, or simply use `gcc file.o -o file`, but this is not my point. My point is how to make `lli` to not include any external libraries (like libc) and just run only my code, and maybe define my own entry point, so I can include any prepared `libc` or any other library at will, I know I can overwrite names of functions and that should work, but then I cannot be sure what was rewritten, so I would be happy if `lli` throws an error if `printf` was used but not defined. Or maybe I got things wrong and `lli` cannot perform in such bare environment.

Comment: I found out that with `lli -entry-function=_start file.ll` I can select any entry point. But still do not know how to strip interpreter of preloaded code. There is option `-extra-object=<object>` but I cannot find option to disable all objects loaded by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: use `lli` without JIT and will probably work:

```
lli -force-interpreter main.bc
```

More info:

In general, it depends on a type of JIT engine you use under the hood (if any).

I can't speak about MCJIT (`-jit-kind=mcjit`) because I am not familiar with it, but I can assure you that this is not possible if you use ORC JIT (`-jit-kind=orc-mcjit` or `-jit-kind=orc-lazy`). However, this is true only for `lli`, if you decide to use ORC on your own, then you can control this behavior.

In the context of `lli` ORC loads not only your module/external objects but also the whole program's address space as well. It means that you get all the libc and the whole LLVM itself.

Depending on your needs you may try to use `lli` truly as an interpreter, though it will be slower since no JIT is involved anymore.

Just add `-force-interpreter` option, and you will be good to go, with few exceptions. These functions still will be executed normally:

```
void Interpreter::initializeExternalFunctions() {
  sys::ScopedLock Writer(*FunctionsLock);
  (*FuncNames)["lle_X_atexit"]       = lle_X_atexit;
  (*FuncNames)["lle_X_exit"]         = lle_X_exit;
  (*FuncNames)["lle_X_abort"]        = lle_X_abort;

  (*FuncNames)["lle_X_printf"]       = lle_X_printf;
  (*FuncNames)["lle_X_sprintf"]      = lle_X_sprintf;
  (*FuncNames)["lle_X_sscanf"]       = lle_X_sscanf;
  (*FuncNames)["lle_X_scanf"]        = lle_X_scanf;
  (*FuncNames)["lle_X_fprintf"]      = lle_X_fprintf;
  (*FuncNames)["lle_X_memset"]       = lle_X_memset;
  (*FuncNames)["lle_X_memcpy"]       = lle_X_memcpy;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have tried it already, maybe the problem is I am using ` LLVM version 5.0.0svn` fresh from official git. I was afraid that the problem is that I have access to all functions that interpreter had preloaded for itselt. Anyway, thanks for answer!

Comment: I wonder If I can use `mcjit-remote-process` to achieve more bare environment, but "standard" remote process `https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/master/tools/lli/ChildTarget/ChildTarget.cpp` does not look promising.

Comment: I would recommend to setup your custom JIT stack. Very basic custom lli is rather easy and small. Feel free to drop me a line if you need assistance 1101.debian@gmail.com